# How to stop a ajax request on user intention or method in code behind by a button click event?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

Actually i am getting a dataset from DB but it is consuming sometime (>1 minutes).

So i use ajax to run asynchronously to check whether the dataset has returned result and at the same time displaying a waiting page.

However , for times, if the user want to navigate to other page instead of waiting the returned result, is there anyone who can give
 me a hint on doing that?

Comment: Are you using AjaxControltoolKit? In frameworks like EXTJs, you can actually specify time out period for an Ajax request or you can cancel the active Ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

I would first try to optimize your query from the database. Any query that is running > 1 minute is is either ridiculously huge (which you could implement pagination to circumvent) ... or is in need of some optimizing perhaps even the indexing on the tables as well.

If that still doesn't yield fast enough response times then here are two approaches for your problem:

1. Whenever the user wants to hit this long running query, run it in a pop up window. This will allow the user to continue navigation in the main web app.
2. Take your pages and start showing them in an iframe. You can then make the request in the parent frame while the user is navigating other pages (which are being loaded in the child frame). Since the parent frame won't be reloaded in this scenario, the ajax request can complete uninterrupted in the parent frame.

Comment: Also you can rebuild you entire site in Javascript with a framework like Backbone or Knockout..

Comment: Although that is plausible, I doubt it's a realistic option. But you are right, it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the scripts and codes your are using in this scenario will not help you!
Better optimize your Database model.

- create tables with clustered index.
- use stored procedure,
- if that too slow create your own Function and Views.
- Users will not view more than 10,000 records on a single page. Depends on the process can  restrict your data  and its optional.... but not the right way!

Once you have sent any request you cannot stop it or navigate when loader is running up.
for Asynchronous data Processing Loader (waiting page) is not Required.

Try this hope It will Help....